# Не могу понять сообщение об ошибке

Tags: c

Начал решать задания на Codewars.
Вот на этой задаче споткнулся: Complete the function that accepts a string parameter, and reverses each word in the string. All spaces in the string should be retained.
Отправляю свою программу на тесты и получаю вот такое сообщение: The expression (as strings) (expected) == (submitted) is false.
Не пойму что это значит.

На моем установленном компиляторе программа работает как надо. Сообщение об ошибке как будто говорит, что надо в другом формате возвращать значение из функции? Я возвращаю указатель на строку.

Вот моя программа:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char* reverseWords(const char* text) {
  int i, n;

    char tmp;
    char output[300];
    char *s, *res;
    strcpy (output, "");
    strcpy (output, text); //Копирую аргумент функции в строку
    res = s = output;      //Это указатели на начало строки
        while(*(s+=strspn(s, " \t\n"))) { //Двигаюсь по строке указателем s, 
                                          //s устанавливается на начало слова  
            n = strcspn(s, " \t \n");    
            for (i=0; i<n-1; i++, n--) { //Меняю местами символы слов
                tmp = *(s+i);
                *(s+i)=*(s+n-1);
                *(s+n-1)=tmp;
            }
        s+=strcspn(s," \t\n"); //Передвигаю указатель на конец слова
        }

  return res;
  }
```

Comment: Ну, вообще-то менять надо не буквы в словах а сами слова.

Comment: Нет, в задании написано разворачивает каждое слово в строке.
вот примеры оттуда: "This is an example!" ==> "sihT si na !elpmaxe"
"double  spaces"      ==> "elbuod  secaps"

Answer (score 3):

Сообщение об ошибке просто говорит о том, что результат работы вашей функции (submitted) не совпадает с эталонным (expected).

Вы возвращаете указатель на локальную переменную из вашей функции `reverseWords`. Ваша функция неработоспосбна в принципе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я еще не изучил динамическое выделение памяти. Без него тут получается никак не обойтись?

Comment: Обойтись. Но это зависит. Откуда вы взяли такой тип функции `char* reverseWords(const char* text)`? Это в задании так жестко задано?

Comment: Да именно требования такие жестко. Как я понимаю, аргумент у функции - строка константа, а возвращать функция должна указатель на другую строку. Я бы смог сделать без этих требований, а с ними не получается. И функции main у меня в распоряжении нет. 
И еще если выше функции объявить переменную (вроде как это глобальная считается?), то так тоже не работает. Она видимо так не считается глобальной.

Comment: @Romaru: Ну тогда либо динамическое выделение, либо `static char output[300];`. А вы уверены, что `300` хватит? Откуда взялось `300`?

Comment: 300 это я просто так сделал. Там первый тест дается слово "apple". Мне 300 на него точно хватало. Спасибо за помощь! Буду изучать то, что Вы подсказали.